# How to extract only a match group without the rest of the sentence?

Tags: r, regex

I'm looking after extracting the fiscal year month + day of month from strings like this one

```
Fiscal year end: September 30; reporting period for blablablabla
Fiscal year end: March 31; reporting period for blablablabla
```

As you can see, all string start with Fiscal year end, a colon, a space, the month, a space, the day of month, a semi colon, and useless text

My regex :

```
sub("^Fiscal year end: ([A-Za-z]*?\\s\\d*);","\\1", "Fiscal year end: March 31; reporting period for")
```

The result :

```
[1] "March 31 reporting period for"
```

What I expected : March 31 (because I specified a match group). I guess the rest doesn't match and is thus unmodified, but what would be a clean way to get ONLY the match group ?

I found a workaround with stringr, by using:

```
str_match("Fiscal year end: March 31; reporting period for", "^Fiscal year end: ([A-Za-z]*?\\s\\d*);")
```

which gives a matrix one element of which is the match group:

```
     [,1]                         [,2]      
[1,] "Fiscal year end: March 31;" "March 31"
```

so that taking `[1,2]` out of the result gives what I want, but I guess there is an easier way.

Comment: Note that you are not using `perl=TRUE` in the `sub`, so, the PCRE tag should be removed, you are actually using a TRE regex flavor where `.` matches any character including a newline.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what does tre stand for

Comment: @rawr: I have never thought about what the abbreviation means. Surely, sime "regular expressions". See http://laurikari.net/tre/about/ for more details, but I cannot find the exact `T` explanation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was thinking it is _the_ regular expressions but was hoping to be wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `.*` at the end that will match any 0+ chars in your *TRE* regex pattern:

```
sub("^Fiscal year end: ([A-Za-z]+\\s*\\d+);.*","\\1", "Fiscal year end: March 31; reporting period for")
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/1LrAW6)

Note I made `[A-Za-z]+` pattern greedy (it seems more natural as there will be some letters anyway) and added a `+` quantifier after it and `\d` to match 1 or more chars (these seem obligatory in your scenario).

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `Fiscal year end:`  - a sequence of literal chars
- `([A-Za-z]+\\s*\\d+)` - Group 1 capturing

  - `[A-Za-z]+` - 1 or more letters
  - `\\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\\d+` - 1+ digits
- `;` - a semi-colon
- `.*` - *any 0+ chars including linebreak symbols, up to the end of string*.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now : my regex didn't match anything after the semicolon, so sub was simply leaving it there. Now yours does match everything, so the sub replaces with only the matching group.

Answer (score 1):

You may parse the string as `Date` and then pick relevant parts with `format`:

```
format(as.Date(x, format = "Fiscal year end: %B %d"), "%B %d") 
# [1] "September 30" "March 31"
```

---

In the `format` argument of `as.Date`, you may include not only the conversion specification (introduced by `%`) but also other characters; See the Details section of `?strptime`:

> [a]ny character in the format string not part of a conversion specification is interpreted literally.

...and:

> Each input string is processed as far as necessary for the format specified: any trailing characters are ignored.

But also note the *Note* in `?as.Date`:

> If the date string does not specify the date completely, the returned answer may be system-specific. The most common behaviour is to assume that a missing year, month or day is the current one. If it specifies a date incorrectly, reliable implementations will give an error and the date is reported as `NA`.

---

```
x <- c("Fiscal year end: September 30; reporting period for blablablabla", 
       "Fiscal year end: March 31; reporting period for blablablabla")
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your strings' pattern:

> As you can see, all string start with Fiscal year end, a colon, a space, the month, a space, the day of month, a semi colon, and useless text

You could also do this:

```
sub(";.*$","", sub("Fiscal year end: ", "", str))

#[1] "September 30" "March 31"
```

---

```
str <- c("Fiscal year end: September 30; reporting period for blablablabla", 
       "Fiscal year end: March 31; reporting period for blablablabla")
```